# Bounty award allocation while suspended

Tags: support, bounty

I noticed the [How can I remove DRM from my Kindle books?](https://superuser.com/questions/258608/how-can-i-remove-drm-from-my-kindle-books) featured-bounty question but I also noticed that the user account only has 1 rep so I looked at the account and saw it was suspended network wide for a year or so but the bounty ends in 5 days and seems to still be valid.

[image]

[image]

### Question

1. If someone posts a question and offers a bounty on the question, and then afterwards their account gets suspended for a longer duration than the bounty period, **will the suspended "bounty-offering" account be able to award the bounty fully 100% to an answer if they get one that suffices for their need and they feel is worthy of it?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, this has happened on before - and the user in question reported that he couldn't. You *cannot* award a bounty while suspended..

We don't *typically* refund bounties when a user is suspended. If a question needs to be closed, and the bounty is stopping that from happening, we will do so.

You can get the "half" bounty amount from having posted after the question is bountied, and having at least +2 and having more upvotes than any other eligible question if any, since the bounty isn't/can't be awarded manually

Comment: How did the user communicate they couldn't award the bounty if they were suspended?

Comment: On main meta as opposed to site meta